# Remove Excel area chart delimiting lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following chart in Excel:

[image: Area chart]

How do I remove the red lines in the limits of the areas and in between the two shaded areas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a standard Area Chart and the lines are the Area outlines, you can:
    1) Turn off the outlines
    2) Add the same data set as an XY/Scatter Chart (resulting in a combination chart)
    3) Format your XY data series lines to match your solid/dashed schema